# Why might my ClickOnce application try to connect to localdb?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, clickonce

I've built a WinForms app using C# and Entity Framework. The data is all in SQL Server. I can verify that the connection string correctly references this database and returns the expected data. Everything works fine when I run it in VS, or even I run the output directly.

The problems started when I deployed it as a ClickOnce application. All of a sudden, I'm getting the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

When I search for this error, most of the results seem to be about a) asp applications and/or b) about the fact that the application is trying to connect to a non-existant instance of localdb.

I've got as far as localising the issue to the initialisation of my data context. Bit hard to debug though, as it runs fine from within VS.

For what it's worth, my connection string is set to the following (in the App.Config files of both my data model library project and the winforms project):

> <parameter value="Server=ARUK-SRV2;Data Source=ARUK-SRV2\ARUKSQL;Initial Catalog=TPS;Integrated Security=True" />

Has anyone come across this before? Does anyone have any suggestions for fixing it?

Comment: Your application is only available onlline or is available offline too?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Offline too - will this make a difference? The machine I'm testing on definitely has an open line to the database.

Comment: May be using an old version of deployment that tries to use local database. Have you tried running application from its publish page? Increase version and the specify a required version in publish settings and publish application and test result. Also you can uninstall application from control panel and install the new version.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Have tried all that. What's odd is that I moved away from localdb to SQL server long before I tried deploying as ClickOnce

Comment: Ctrl-F, search *entire solution* for `attachdbfilename`.

Comment: Sam's offer is one of the first things that should be checked.

Using solution configuration management, ensure that all of your projects included in build. Close Vsual studio and Delete bin and obj folders completelye, Run `rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache` to clean clickonce cache. Open visual studio, rebuild and publish again.

Comment: @SamAxe Thanks for the hint Sam - managed to find an issue with the default connection factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sam Axe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243884/why-might-my-clickonce-application-try-to-connect-to-localdb?noredirect=1#comment52369722_32243884) suggested searching for attachdbfilename. This resulted in 0 results, but did give me an idea. I searched for "localdb" and found three hits - one in each of my App.Config files.

Whilst I had changed the connection string to point at our SQL Server instance, I had left the default connection factory set to LocalDbConnectionFactory. (D'oh!)

David Obando has a [blog post explaining what needs to be changed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidobando/archive/2012/08/14/changing-ef-s-default-provider-from-localdb-to-sql-server.aspx). In essence, it amounts to changing

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
```

to

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
```

Thanks for the pointers!